# HDMI @ 1920x1080 and 3.5" TFT @ 640x480 Retropie

Tags: retropie

Does anyone know how I can set 2 different resolutions? Like have my HDMI @ 1920x1080 and 3.5" TFT @ 640x480. So that when my tft is by itself it displays the proper resolution and when it's hooked to HDMI it uses the HDMI resolution.